# How to create loop for opposite or reverse classes in Sass?

Tags: sass

Have two different classes and they have values that are opposite to one another. Is there a way to write them in Sass through an optimized way?

For example:

```
.left-column{
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
.right-column{
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);
}
```

These two classes are quite similar, except for some of the values being either reversed (right/left) and one negative while the other positive. I wish to be able to change their values more easily through one medium and have it change relatively for both when generating for the CSS (say I change the rotation to 45, from 30, and it would change to 45 and -45 respectively).

Currently I have this setup:

```
@each $direction, $distinctions in (
left: (left, right, 30),
right: (right, left, 30)
) {
    $_float: nth($distinctions, 1);
    $_padding: nth($distinctions, 2);
    $_transformation: nth($distinctions, 3);

    .#{$direction}-column {
        float: #{$_float};
        margin: 20px;
        padding-#{$_padding}: 20px;
        transform: rotateY(30deg * #{$_transformation});

        border-color: darken($primary-color, $min-difference-amount) $_border-color-right darken($primary-color, $min-difference-amount) $_border-color-left;
        #{$_ribbon-position}: -30px;
    }
}
```

I don't even mind creating a new mixin or function seeing as this scenario will probably repeat itself a lot.

Comment: I like it! It wasn't immediately clear what was happening, so it may be a compromise of readability for reducing duplication. Hopefully there will be some cleaner ways to do this in the near future. There's a [feature request on github](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1582) for content functions. We'll see..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider only 2 "directions", the solution could be easier.

```
@mixin mirror($side1) {
  $side2: right;
  $k1: 1;
  @if $side1 == right {
    $side2: left;
    $k1: -1;
  }
  $k2: $k1 * -1;

  float: $side1;
  margin: 20px * $k1;
  padding-#{$side2}: 20px;
  transform: rotateY(30deg * $k2);
}

.left-column {
  @include mirror(left);
}
.right-column {
  @include mirror(right);
}
```

Here we have 2 opposite coefficients and 2 opposite "sides". The SCSS above is compiled to:

```
.left-column {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
}

.right-column {
  float: right;
  margin: -20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
```